# Odd debugger behavior with Interface and Generics on 64bit OS when toggling 'Prefer 32-Bit

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5, anycpu

I have come across this odd behaviour: when my projects settings are set to `Any CPU` and `Prefer 32-bit` on a `64bit Windows 7 OS` the `.Net 4.5`program below works as expected. If however I turn off `Prefer 32-bit` then when stepping through the program, I can see that the code never steps into the interface implementation - but also does not throw any errors.

I have distilled it down to its simplest form in the following console application:

```
namespace BugCheck
{
    interface IBroken
    {
        bool Broken<TValue> (TValue gen, Large large);
    }
    class Broke : IBroken
    {
        public bool Broken<TValue> (TValue gen, Large large )
        { return true; }
    }
    struct Large
    {
        int a, b, c;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //32bit can step in. 64bit can't
            ((IBroken)new Broke()).Broken(1, new Large());
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, when toggling `Prefer 32-bit` the program will alternate between the .net 32bit assemblies and the 64bit assemblies - where it works as expected with the 32bit assemblies and "breaks silently" with the 64bit assemblies.

As suggested by @Athari it appears to be related to the size of the Large struct.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like a 4.0 debugger bug to me, the 2.0 debugger has no trouble with it.  Nothing anybody here can fix for you, report this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, will follow that route -- just want to make sure I am not falling into the trap of assuming it a bug, if the bug is just my ignorance :) 

I Seemed to have trouble logging via the browser, so fell back on integrated feedback in VS ( so probably logged in incorrect location ) https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/943122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that come across this question looking for a solution, to quote [Tom from the Microsoft team](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/943122):

> This looks like it is related to a bug that is fixed in .NET Framework 4.5.2. We can verify that that the issue is related by disabling the Managed Return Value feature. I have posted instructions for doing this to the 'Workarounds' section.
>
> This issue is caused by the code which gathers return values. It is
>   possible to work around the issue by disabling Managed return values.
>
> 1. Go to the System properties (Win8: WinKey+X, select ‘System’, Win7: Open ‘Properties’ from my computer)
> 2. Advanced System Settings
> 3. Environment Variables…
> 4. Click ‘New’ and add
>
>    - Name: VSDebug_DisableManagedReturnValue
>    - Value: 1
>
> If disabling Managed Return Values works around the issue, the fix for
>   this issue is in .NET Framework 4.5.2. This can be downloaded from
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642.
>   Installing 4.5.2 is all that is needed to fix the issue.